# Show that $GL(2, \Bbb Q)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL(3, \Bbb Q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, linear-groups

What should be my approach for this particular question and general approach to prove isomorphism of one group to another ?

Comment: If you're not sure how to approach a problem like this, you should start by reviewing the relevant definitions. To show that two groups are isomorphic, you should find an isomorphism between them: that is, a [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) [group homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism). In this problem, since any subgroup of $GL(3,\Bbb Q)$ is acceptable, we only need an *injective* homomorphism $f:GL(2,\Bbb Q)\to GL(3,\Bbb Q)$. The image of this $f$ is the needed subgroup.

Comment: In general, $GL_n(K)$ is a subgroup of $GL_{n+1}(K)$ for every field $K$. Consider the "obvious" embedding. Also try first the case $n=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Just consider $\mathcal i: GL(2,\Bbb Q) \hookrightarrow GL(3,\Bbb Q)$ given by

$\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} &a_{12} \\ a_{21} &a_{22}\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 &0\\ 0 &a_{11} &a_{12} \\ 0 &a_{21} &a_{22}\end{pmatrix}$